# Creating a responsive "list" with image and button on Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-5

I've been trying to implement a container where I have 4 images side-by-side, and a button under each of them. When the screen's size changes, the "items" inside should be responsive and keep the button along with them. This is what I have until now:

```
<pre><code>
<div class="container-md">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="img1.png">
            <button class="btn mt-2 btn-secondary">Button 1</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="img2.png"">
            <button class="btn mt-2 btn-secondary">Button 2</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="img3.png">        
            <button class="btn mt-2 btn-secondary">Button 3</button>       
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="img4.png">  
            <button class="btn mt-2 btn-secondary">Button 4</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</code></pre>
```

It should behave as the drawings below:
**Big screen size:**

[image: Big screen size]

**Medium screen size**

[image: Medium screen size]

**Small screen size**

[image: Small screen size]

But, in my code, the images are way too big, the buttons are on the same line as the images and it's not responsive at all (used emoji images as examples):

[image: Actual result]

I know I should resize the images first, but I've tried many ways and I'm not sure which one is the most appropriate.
Also, styling tips are very welcome

Comment: Why `col-md-3` then?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With Bootstrap classes, perhaps start by try adding [`img-fluid`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/content/images/#responsive-images) class to `img` so that the images can scale with the parent width.

Also, try define some [responsive classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/grid/#responsive-classes) for `col`, such as `col-sm-6`, `col-md-6` and `col-lg-3` classes, so that the column placement of `div` changes with the viewport width.

If the `button` need to fill the width of parent `div`, try wrap it with a `div` with `d-grid` as recommended by the Bootstrap [document](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/buttons/#block-buttons).

Lastly, perhaps consider to add a [vertical gutter](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/gutters/#vertical-gutters) in Bootstrap by also adding a `gy-3` class to the `div` as `row`, so that there will be spaces between the elements when wrapped.

Example with the modifications: (changed the `src` to use dummy images)

```html
<link
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
  integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>

<div class="container-md">
  <div class="row gy-3">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000?random=1" class="img-fluid" />
      <div class="d-grid">
        <button class="btn mt-2 btn-secondary">Button 1</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000?random=2" class="img-fluid" />
      <div class="d-grid">
        <button class="btn mt-2 btn-secondary">Button 2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000?random=3" class="img-fluid" />
      <div class="d-grid">
        <button class="btn mt-2 btn-secondary">Button 3</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000?random=4" class="img-fluid" />
      <div class="d-grid">
        <button class="btn mt-2 btn-secondary">Button 4</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```